# cassandra is logging timeout of node URGENT_MESSAGES

Tags: kubernetes, cassandra

URGENT_MESSAGES-[no-channel] dropping message of type GOSSIP_DIGEST_SYN whose timeout expired before reaching the network

Comment: check, if node is alive

    nodetool status

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for your message. Yesterday we solved the Problem.
The reason was a "dead node" oviously leaved form a change in the kubernetes deployment.
So, allways look out for dead nodes, after changing something in the cluster deployment.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't provide a lot of information but I'm assuming that your cluster is running into a known issue where gossip messages are being dropped during startup of a Cassandra node ([CASSANDRA-16877](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-16877)).

The starting node sends `GOSSIP_DIGEST_SYN` with a high priority (`URGENT_MESSAGES`) but for large clusters, Cassandra 4.0 nodes cannot serialise the gossip state when the size of the state exceeds 128kb and no acknowledgement gets sent. Since a node can not gossip with other nodes, it fails to start.

This was urgently fixed in Cassandra 4.0.1 last year. Upgrade the binaries on the affected Cassandra 4.0 nodes and that should allow them to start successfully and join the ring. Cheers!